# php date function with timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a little problem with timestamp. When i try to get current date with

```
$datestring = date("Y-m-d");
```

I get the correct date as 2012-11-14.

But with this little script

```
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("Y"), date("m"), date("d"));
echo $timestamp . "<br />";
echo gmdate("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

I get 2182-08-10 at the end. Any ideas?

**Followup Question**

With

```
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
echo $timestamp . "<br />";
echo gmdate("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

I now get 2012-11-13. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function signature is:

```
mktime ([ int $hour = date("H") [, int $minute = date("i") [, int $second = date("s") [, int $month = date("n") [, int $day = date("j") [, int $year = date("Y") [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )
```

The order is hour, minute, second, **month, day, year**, not year, month, day.

Yay American conventions (?).

Comment: **Followup Question**

With 

    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
 echo $timestamp . "<br />";
 echo gmdate("Y-m-d", $timestamp);

I now get 2012-11-13. Why is that?

Comment: Have you set *your* timezone correctly, so the GM offset is calculated correctly? `date_default_timezone_set`.